# Which framework to use to embed interactive scala code editor + shell in a reveal.js presentation?

Tags: scala, interactive, reveal.js

Everything is in the title,

I saw a presentation about scala done in reveal.js (I guess), some slides contained text boxes in which scala code could be edited/executed and the the output of the program was also dynamically refreshed in the slide.

Ideally I'd like to find a way to set up something similar to this:

https://leanprover.github.io/tutorial/index.html

except that the left text would be slides instead of a single page.

I'm not very proficient in browser-based tech so I'm asking for help.

Comment: Do not add unrelated tags!